# Find file containing class during runtime

Tags: php

I have a class `Foo` it is available during run-time but i can't find it inside my project folder. it's not a core PHP class or any PHP extension.

I have already tried `ReflectionClass` i don't have it in my server.

hoping to call some function like `functionName($Foo);` and get the location of the file containing that file.

Comment: why cant you search entire project with `function Foo` ?

Comment: `grep -r 'class Foo' /`

Comment: @deceze and Suresh Kamrushi I have already user grep, and searched using IDE also

Comment: Perhaps a long shot, but do you have an autoloader function that dynamically defines the class if it cannot be loaded from a file?

Comment: @MichaelRushton no i checked the autoloader class too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found how to locate it now `get_included_files()` this function will give a long list of included files i just looked through and found it. Files can be included form ini.